# How to access aks service from same vnet?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-networking, aks, azure-application-gateway

I have created an aks cluster and deployed an application there and exposed it as a service.

Can be accessible through LoadBalancer.

To access it internally, I created a windows VM in the same vnet (different subnet) of aks cluster and tried to access the application using cluster IP, but can't access it.

Any suggestions?

Because I got the similar issue with application gateway also, so tried this VM now but same issue.